# RHEL hangs after starting virt-who succesfully

Tags: redhat, rhel6

**Idea #1:** Is there a way to REPAIR an RHEL 6.2 installation?

---

During the start-up procedure, after a recent forced reboot, my Linux machine (RHEL 6.2) hangs right after successfully starting virt-who. I can use login screens (Alt + F2/F3...) in text mode.

I am clueless -- how can I find out what is the next step in the startup sequence? That step is most likely what is causing it to hang.

These are the last lines saved to **/var/log/boot.log**:

```
Starting RPC idmapd: [60G[[0;32m  OK  [0;39m]
Starting cups: [60G[[0;32m  OK  [0;39m]
Starting acpi daemon: [60G[[0;32m  OK  [0;39m]
Starting HAL daemon: [60G[[0;32m  OK  [0;39m]
Starting PC/SC smart card daemon (pcscd): [60G[[0;32m  OK  [0;39m]
Retrigger failed udev events[60G[[0;32m  OK  [0;39m]
Loading autofs4: [60G[[0;32m  OK  [0;39m]
Starting automount: [60G[[0;32m  OK  [0;39m]
Enabling Bluetooth devices:
Starting sshd: [60G[[0;32m  OK  [0;39m]
Starting ntpd: [60G[[0;32m  OK  [0;39m]
Starting mysqld:  [60G[[0;32m  OK  [0;39m]
Starting postfix: [60G[[0;32m  OK  [0;39m]
Starting abrt daemon: [60G[[0;32m  OK  [0;39m]
Starting ksm: [60G[[0;32m  OK  [0;39m]
Starting ksmtuned: [60G[[0;32m  OK  [0;39m]
Starting Qpid AMQP daemon: [60G[[0;32m  OK  [0;39m]
Starting crond: [60G[[0;32m  OK  [0;39m]
Starting atd: [60G[[0;32m  OK  [0;39m]
Starting libvirtd daemon: [60G[[0;32m  OK  [0;39m]
Starting rhsmcertd 240 1440[60G[[0;32m  OK  [0;39m]
Starting virt-who: [60G[[0;32m  OK  [0;39m]
```

Comment: What makes you say it is hanging? If you can you login from the text consoles, then this is a problem of X/graphical desktop not starting, and we should take it from there.

Comment: I could only start the text console after disabling redgb noquiet and restarting from the boot loader entry. Before that, it would just freeze in the RHEL splash screen.

Comment: Looks a video card problem to me... if you login and type startx, does it succed?

Comment: xinit fails with 'cannot detect screens'

Answer (score 1):

Get the init level of your system:

```
[root@rhel6 ~]# INIT_LEVEL=$(cat /etc/inittab |tail -n1|cut -d":" -f2)
[root@rhel6 ~]# echo $INIT_LEVEL
3
```

List the services starting in this run level(they are ordered in the startup order), get the line after virt-who in your case:

```
[root@rhel6 ~]# find /etc/rc${INIT_LEVEL}.d/S*
/etc/rc3.d/S02lvm2-monitor
/etc/rc3.d/S08ip6tables
/etc/rc3.d/S08iptables
/etc/rc3.d/S10network
/etc/rc3.d/S11auditd
/etc/rc3.d/S12rsyslog
/etc/rc3.d/S25netfs
/etc/rc3.d/S26udev-post
/etc/rc3.d/S55sshd
/etc/rc3.d/S80postfix
/etc/rc3.d/S90crond
/etc/rc3.d/S97rhnsd
/etc/rc3.d/S97rhsmcertd
/etc/rc3.d/S99local
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a recent bug. I had same issue last week.

http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=5636

Comment: This doesn't appear to have any relevance to the question.

Comment: Doesn't, but I had same issue while running virt-who :)